# Check the random number by modulo and user's input

Tags: c

im trying to determine how many times the user has guess right the number and place of a random number.

> for example, if the number is 1234 and the user's input is 7214
>
> so he guess right only the number 2 and 4.
>   because of this: 1[2]3[4] == 7[2]1[4].

problem: the program throws me out after i take the user's input. im getting an error which says: "Expression: result_pointer != nullptr"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int hit(int num);
int strike(int num);
int rndNum(int num);

void main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int chosenNum;
    int saveHits;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("The Random number: %d", chosenNum = rndNum(num));
    printf("\nPlease enter a 4 digit number: ");
    scanf("%d", num);
    saveHits = hit(num, chosenNum);
    printf("\nThe number of hits: %d", saveHits);
    getch();
}
int rndNum(int num)
{
    int rndNum = rand() % 9000 + 1000;

    return rndNum;
}

int hit(int num1, int chosenNum1)
{
    int i, hit1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
            if (num1 % 10 == chosenNum1 % 10)
                hit1++;
            num1 /= 10;
            chosenNum1 /= 10;
    }
    return hit1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `&`

```
scanf("%d", &num);
            ^
```